# How would I make this filter query using pandas

Tags: pandas

Given that I have a data frame:

```
  UID   | booleanCondition
------------------------------
 uid1   |   True
 uid1   |   False
 uid2   |   True
 uid2   |   True
```

How can I find the `UIDs` that have had their `booleanCondition` changed? I know that I can do this by looping through the data frame using the `.as_matrix()` command but is there a way where I don't need to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "changed"? From what? In this instance, do you just want to filter by `booleanCondition == True`? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 df.groupby('UID').filter(lambda x: (x.booleanCondition != x.booleanCondition.shift()).all())
```

Output:

```
        UID  booleanCondition
1   uid1                 True
2   uid1                False
```